# Migrated MySQL database, now seeing "Field doesn't have a default value"

Tags: php, mysql

I was running an older version of MySQL through WAMP, and just migrated the databases to an IIS-based server with PHP and MySQL 5.6 installed.  For any query I run where not all columns of the table are specified, I receive a message such as:

Field 'J_param2' doesn't have a default value

All columns are TEXT and have the "NOT NULL" attribute set, but it's my understanding that NULL and an empty string are different.  I'm fine with the empty string.  Rather than altering the hundreds of tables, is there any easier way to fix this?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the NOT NULL and you should be fine.

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN J_param2 TEXT;
```